# Parsing a client request within IIS7 filter

Tags: c++, iis-7, isapi

what is the most practical way to access form values within a request-level IIS7 http module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like the most practical way is to intercept onbeginrequest and parse all the input manually if the input is either marked as urlencoded or multipart.

Answer (score 0):

From the `HttpContext.Request` object. For example:

```
HttpRequest request = HttpContext.Current.Request;
String myFormValue = request.Form["myFormName"];
```